# kubernetes rest service intra pod communication

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to make rest service calls from one pod to another in the same namespace direct via IP. I have enabled egress from my app to my app as prior to this I was seeing a "connect timed out" error. Now when I try to make a simple actuator call as a test, instead of the expected <200, {"status":"UP"}>, I get this

<302,[Location:"https://[some_ip]:8443/[app_name]/actuator/health", Content-Length:"0", Date:"Wed, 23 Aug 2023 11:02:52 GMT", Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", Connection:"keep-alive", Server:"Application Server"]>

Relevant code snippet:

```
LOGGER.info("Invoking actuator on the other service pod IP {}", v1Pod.getStatus().getPodIP());
final String otherPodEndpoint = "http://" + v1Pod.getStatus().getPodIP() + ":8080/[app_name]/actuator/health";
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(otherPodEndpoint);
LOGGER.info("Invoking actuator on {}", otherPodEndpoint);
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(),
        HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
        });
LOGGER.info("Actuator response: {}", response.getBody());
```

Answer (score 0):

You connected via `http://pod_ip:8080` and your service is trying to redirect you to `https://pod_ip:8443`

[HTTP Response Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)